# Simple <a href> link click counter with Rails 5 without using gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-5, counter, page-refresh

I have a post page with a consistent `<a href="">` link button in it. I need to show **link clicked number** for each post. I already have table columns as

```
t.integer "count_click"
```

**How can I make this counter in the simplest form possible?**

```
<%= link_to @post.reference_title, @post.reference_url, target: :_blank %>
```

I probably can make it happen with a simple SQL query in the Controller, right? But I have no idea how to trigger it with  click

Thank you!

Comment: What about [google analytics event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)? Or, in your app you could make the update in the controller the link is going to.

Comment: How different is the click count going to be with the view count, if every time you click something you view it?

Comment: Hi @user3366016 , no idea about that google thing :) I'm researching that. I tried to do in Controller, but failed. I updated my question.

Comment: Hi @leito , page view and link click are different counter. every visitor to the page won't necessarily click the link. So I need separate counter to trigger at <a href> click

Comment: What do your strong params look like for the controller, are you permitting these fields? Just making sure, `1` in your example is the id of the post right?  For a simple implementation I'd still try and do it in the controllers. In controller that loads the page, increment the `count_view` and in the action that is called from the link increment the `count_click`. But this will only count when those pages are actually loaded (i.e. even direct entry). [Rails docs reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter)

Comment: hey mate, it worked when I did Post.increment_counter(:count_view, @post.id) :D duh! thanks! however still no idea how to do it with <a href> link

Comment: side note, just update your question with new information or ask a new question, don't remove the original question. It makes it hard for others to learn from the comments/question or to offer advice.

Answer (score 1):

For a basic implementation, as per my comments, I'd do it in the controller action. I guess I would do it all in the same action for your example.

For your original question there were 2 counters:

```
t.integer "count_click"
t.integer "count_view"
```

I'd try to add a param to the link itself that would pass when clicking it:

```
<%= link_to @post.reference_title, reference_url(@post, clicked: true), target: :_blank %>
```

For a basic implementation you could increment like this:

```
def reference
  # Increment the view counter whenever page loads.
  Post.increment_counter(:count_view, @post.id)
  # Increment the click counter if the link was clicked based on param.
  Post.increment_counter(:count_click, @post.id) if params[:clicked] == "true"
end
```

Comment: Thanks! count_view works great :) I made a silly obvious mistake in there :) but the count click gives error **wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)** I guess, can't pass it as @post.reference_url(clicked: true)

Comment: @Designer I've updated the link. I'm not sure your routes... and now that i'm looking at this, is that a route in your app or is that an attribute on your model that stores a URL? Does that URL go to a page in your app?

Comment: Now I get **undefined method `reference_url' for #<#<Class:0x007fea78ac1c90>:0x007fea7e8197d0>** error. but I see what you are suggesting there. I'm trying variations of implementing that **clicked:true** in there. thanks